# Email protocol, mail server change and using another protocol from exist hosting

Tags: email, smtp, hosting, cpanel, nameservers

I have a domain which name is asifulmamun.info

Then, I've purchased a hosting for host website and connect this domain to hosting with cpanel by nameserver change.

I've create an email with this domain from Cpanel i.e. xx@asifulmamun.info.

Hosting provider told me that, my email has a limit for sending or receiving up to (25-30) email per hour.

But, if i will need to send/receive more than email from limitation how can I do this?

*I think it's using my hosting server protocol for using mail email service.*

Is it possible using another service provider protocol for using more than email from hosting server protocol?

Is it possible to use gmail server without purchase google cloude?

**Is it possible, my domain will host in my exist hosting (Cpanel) and mail protocol using another service provider i.e. google, godaddy, aws or any service provider? If possible how?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use different service providers for incoming emails and for outgoing emails. In particular, you can use several [email service providers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_service_provider_(marketing)) for outgoing emails.

The "how" depends on what you want to do. I recently wrote a lengthy [article on email](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/). You find answers to all protocol-related questions there. The sections about email's [architecture](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#simplified-architecture) and its [entities](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#entities) might be especially interesting to you.